# Java 8: Using Comparator.comparing when comparing values from a map based on given keys

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have written a comparator which compares string keys based on the value they correspond to in a predefined map.

```
 private Comparator<String> periodComparator() {
    return (s1, s2) -> {
      return periodMap.get(s1).compareTo(periodMap.get(s2));
    };
  }
```

However, IntelliJ is highlighting this to tell me that it can be replaced by `Comparator.comparing` (or something similar). I can't see how this could be possible. Is IntelliJ flagging up a false positive here or is there really a more succinct way to do this using Java 8 magic?

Comment: I have added pictures to my answer, check below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ and it suggests that it can be replaced, simply move your mouse cursor to the line in question (to the code in question) and press Alt + Enter, you will get a menu of options, one of them will be to replace your current code with what IntelliJ suggests, so just do that and you will see how it's supposed to be based on IDEA's suggestion.

Will EDIT and add pictures.

Example:

[image]

After you press Alt + Enter:

[image]

After you finally select for IntelliJ to replace your code, final result is:

[image]

So there you go.

Comment: IntelliJ never ceases to amaze me. Thanks, I don't know why I didn't know this earlier.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
Comparator<String> periodComparator = Comparator.comparing(periodMap::get)
```

Or as a method, same thing:

```
private Comparator<String> periodComparator(){
  return Comparator.comparing(periodMap::get);
}
```

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer, but hey! u have no pictures ;)

Comment: @Eugene What's the difference between his and my answer ? By doing what I posted he will get same code like Chirlo provided.

Comment: @GCP it's probably just me - but I don't like the IDE to suggest me these things (on rare occasions I would), I'd like to think that this should be *obvious* for someone writing code and if not it should become so.

Comment: @GCP I focused on answering the "is there really a  more succinct way to do this using Java 8 magic" part of the question, I found it more suitable to answer the question in a generic way instead of using a concrete tool, that way it might be useful for people not using IntelliJ too. Otherwise the question should have a 'intelliJ' tag

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator is a functional interface. So it has only one not static or default method to overwritte.

You use generics to tell the function what kind of objects should be compared. Then you only need to give in a lamda function to define the real comparsion logic.

All other functionality is defined by default methods (that's the magic ;))